# Autodesk forge - don’t have permission to access this API

Tags: data-management, autodesk-data-management

I have a consultation about the data management API of 'autodesk platform services'.
I am trying to use the [GET hub endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/).
I am using 'postman' to send the request.
When I send a GET hub request using a three-legged token, I get a warning in the response.

```
“meta”:{
    “warnings”:[
        {
            “Id”:null,
            “HttpStatusCode”:”403”,
            “ErrorCode”:BIM360DM_ERROR,
            “Title”:”Unable to get hubs from BIM 360DM US.”,
            “Detail”:”You don’t have permission to access this API”,
            “AbouLink”:null,
            “Source”:null,
            “meta”:null
        },
        {
            “Id”:null,
            “HttpStatusCode”:”403”,
            “ErrorCode”:BIM360DM_ERROR,
            “Title”:”Unable to get hubs from BIM 360DM EMEA.”,
            “Detail”:”You don’t have permission to access this API”,
            “AbouLink”:null,
            “Source”:null,
            “meta”:null
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the cause?

I made a GET hub request using a three-legged token.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be very similar to [Autodesk forge - don't have permission to access hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401325/autodesk-forge-dont-have-permission-to-access-hub?rq=2). Have you tried the answer provided there?

The process of enabling access to BIM360, ACC, or Fusion Teams projects is also explained here: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/#provision-access-in-other-products.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Enabling access to BIM360 resolved the issue.